# Div not displaying in Chrome and Safari but does in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a div containing a chart that displays correctly in FF but not in chrome and safari.

FF:
[image]

Chrome:
[image]

http://scm.ulster.ac.uk/~b00557543/RugbyOne/jquery_demos.html

the wierd thing is, when using chrome's dev tools and I untick width, the chart appears but then will disappear again when I try to interact and if i remove width from the css file the graph does not show.
[image]

Comment: try optimising the svg: http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor

Comment: have you get any console error.if then tell us. @Chris

Answer (score 3):

Try adding:

```
#two{
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: better to use `min-width` css property.

Answer (score 0):

```
#two{
float: right;
position: relative;
}
```